# Horizontal scroll for uilabel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uilabel

How can i  write code for making horizontal scroll for the array of uilabel

Example:

```
 NSArray *tagsArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:someData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
if ([tagsArray count]>0) {
for (int i=0; i<[tagsArray count]; i++) {
CGRect ansCountValueRectangle13 = CGRectMake(80*i+10,110,80,30);
UILabel  *_tagsValue = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:ansCountValueRectangle13];
    _tagsValue.clipsToBounds=YES;
    _tagsValue.tag=250;
    _tagsValue.text = [tagsArray objectAtIndex:i];
    _tagsValue.layer.cornerRadius=15.0;
    _tagsValue.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    _tagsValue.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    _tagsValue.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    _tagsValue.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
    [testing addSubview: _tagsValue];
}
}
```

for this i have to add `UIScrollView` ,these code written inside of `tableViewCell` and i want each tableview row have `Horizontal Scroll` with `UILabel`

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have to do is add the label to scrollView and add scrollView to table view cell  content view:

```
// You have to change the scroll frame to match your requirements
    UIScrollView *sv = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 10.0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 35)]; 
    sv.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor]; // I've added color to see when the scroll view is layout
    float svWidth = 10; //Margin to content view width (feel fee to change it or remove it)
    if ([tagsArray count]>0) {
        for (int i=0; i<[tagsArray count]; i++) {
            CGRect ansCountValueRectangle13 = CGRectMake(80*i+10,2,80,30);
            UILabel  *_tagsValue = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:ansCountValueRectangle13];
            _tagsValue.clipsToBounds=YES;
            _tagsValue.tag=250;
            _tagsValue.text = [tagsArray objectAtIndex:i];
            _tagsValue.layer.cornerRadius=15.0;
            _tagsValue.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
            _tagsValue.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            _tagsValue.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
            _tagsValue.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
            svWidth += 80+10;
            [sv addSubview:_tagsValue];
            // I don't know what is testing, you have to add the labels to scrollView
            //[testing addSubview: _tagsValue];
        }
        // Set the content size of the scroll view, feel free to tweak it
        [sv setContentSize:CGSizeMake(svWidth, 35)];
        // Add scroll view to your cell, I've added it to contentView but maybe you want to add it to some subview
        [cell.contentView addSubview:sv];

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I have done this using Autolayouts, StackView, ScrollView and a Label

Here is link for demo code

https://github.com/pramodBiz/HorizontalLabelScroll

[image]

Comment: What do you use `UIStackView` for? Won't it work with simple `UIView`

Comment: I have a habit of using UIStackView. But I think it must work with simple view

Answer (score 0):

Ramesh, Do you  set content size for scroll view. ie. **testing** in your code

Answer (score 0):

I was able to modify a codebase, originally created by [Włodzimierz Woźniak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4861421/w%C5%82odzimierz-wo%C5%BAniak), so that I could horizontally scroll through tag-labels in a UITableViewCell. The programmatic addition of the UIScrollView as a subview in the UITableViewCell could be changed to allow for the UIScrollView to be a subview for practically any UIView type.

Here is a breakdown of how the code works...

1. Converting Strings to Labels
2. Customizing Labels
3. Converting Labels to Images
4. Converting Images to Attributed text
5. Creating TextView
6. Setting Attributed text to TextView
7. Adding TextView as a subview to ScollView
8. Adding ScrollView as a subview to TableViewCell

You can find a workable demo of the implementation here:

https://github.com/austinmm/WordsAsTagLabels-Example
[image]